# How to view PDF file before uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, preview

I'm implementing some code to to view a PDF file after selecting it from our computer, but I am getting some errors

I have tried with 'pdf.js' but I'm getting some error that 'PDFJS' or 'pdfjsLib' is not defined

```
function showInCanvas(url) {

                'use strict';

                var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(url);

                pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function (pdf) {

                    pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
                        var scale = 1.5;
                        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                        canvas.width = viewport.width;

                        var renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: context,
                            viewport: viewport
                        };
                        page.render(renderContext);
                    });
                });
            }
```

The error message that I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pdfjsLib is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you depend on external library to preview pdf file even you could do it using iframe object.you just need to read file from file control and assign file object to iframe.

```
   var file =document.getElementById("filecontrol").files[0];
   var url =URL.createObjectURL(file );
   $('#iframeid').attr('src',url);
```

HTML :

```
<iframe id="iframeid" width="x" height="y"></iframe>
```